# VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04 LTS guest cannot shutdown

Tags: virtualbox, shutdown, acpi

I have a virtualbox guest running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The host is also an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Virtualbox running is version 4.3.10

When I'm running in the guest and click on the shutdown button, nothing happens at all.
I can shutdown the guest by doing a shutdown now.
Basically trying to send an ACPI shutdown to the guest does not work at all for some reason.

Does anyone know how I can figure out what is going on? I looking in the virtualbox logs for my machine but nothing seems to be written there that could provide some information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the Guest additions? If not, log into the VM to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Finally restart the VM to complete the installation.

ACPI shutdown should halt the VM now.

Comment: At first I had the guest additions provided by virtual box directly. I just uninstalled them and then trying doing your command but I get a weird error:
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                        Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: VM is a desktop or server?

Comment: The Ubuntu is a desktop

Comment: could you check the point release too with `lsb_release -r`, 12.04 or 12.04.4

Comment: I get : Release:        12.04

Comment: sorry it's `lsb_release -d`

Comment: There you go: Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Comment: ok, try to first fix the broken package with `sudo apt-get -y -f build-dep virtualbox-guest-x11`

Comment: if that works, type the command proposed in my answer after the previous one

Comment: The command to fix the broken package worked. I then executed the other command you suggested and I can now perform an ACPI shutdown. Thanks a lot man! Could you just explain quickly what exactly I did? I understand I'm now using the guest additions on the ubuntu software repo? What exactly was the command to fix the package?

Comment: There's an opened [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1160401) related to the broken package situation you encountered. `apt-get -f` fixed the broken packages and build-dep was a workaround to actually get the dependencies needed to install `virtualbox-guest-x11`. Now a final word about the guest additions, when possible always prefer installation from the Ubuntu archives as they are maintained and tested by the Ubuntu community (and by Debian as well).